# UIwebview loaded content flickers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I loaded the html content in a webview. At the same time multiple html files are loaded in another webview (one by one for calculating the page total). When I scroll the first html loaded webview, it is flickering. Scroll time, content loaded 25% and remain content load few sec later (which is vertical 25% of the screen size). I'm using javascript to scroll the content.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{

   if (!webView.isLoading) {

        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
            NSString *padding = @"document.body.style.padding='0px 20px 0px 20px';";
            [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:padding]; 

        }
        else
        {
            NSString *padding = @"document.body.style.padding='0px 40px 0px 40px';";
            [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:padding];

        }
}
```

In the button action script

```
[Mywebview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"javascript:pageScroll(%d, %d);window.TextSelection.setState();", 0,(int )(intcurrentPagesinChap*Mywebview.bounds.size.height)]];
```

Comment: I'm using javascript to scroll the content - why u r using it if u want to scroll the content! u r using webview! So y this?

Comment: @NSS: Move to next and previous page using the UISwipeGestureRecognizer action so that.

Comment: This problem is related to your code, please post your code in the question.

Comment: Just a comment. `if (webView.isLoading)` is enough.. No need to assign "Yes" or "No" and check with `isEqualToString`

Comment: @Praveen: This is not issue. Even I checked no use of that.